# Dealing with Twitter API to authenticate an access token in .NET Core 2.2

Tags: twitter, .net-core, jwt, access-token, twitter-oauth

I'm receiving a Jason Web Token(JWT) in which it contain a Twitter token such as: `1089820349829660672-CGe6naQQxDCgX8dYG7PrUvUiMeAV5k`.

How can I make sure that this token is really returned from twitter??

I know this question have been asked a lot, I found lots of old questions (7 and 5 years ago), but none of em helped me out.

A seven years old answer was to use:

`https://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json?oauth_consumer_key=XXX&oauth_nonce=XXX&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_token=XXX&oauth_timestamp=123456789&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=YYY`

But that didn't work also.

Comment: Have you tried using `https://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json`?

Comment: As mentioned in the question description, I've used it but still nothing happened. If you know how to use it exactly can you please tell me in details ? Thank you for your time and reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After lots of research, I finally found a Library called `TweetInvi`. Which is a C# library that handle and manage all the request to Twitter APIs.
Here's the official documentation for it:
`https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi`

As if we want to validate a user, all we need to do is using:

```
Auth.SetUserCredentials(ConsumerKey,
                        ConsumerSecret,
                        UserAccessToken,
                        UserAccessTokenSecret);
```

Please note that user access token and user access token secret are returned from Twitter when getting a users token